# RAID5 + Samba Woes

Tags: centos, samba, raid-5

I'm in the process of setting up a brand-new CentOS 6.2 server. The boot, swap and root partitions live on a 320GB SSD, and my archive files are on a 9,000 GB RAID array.
   Problem is that if I setup a password-protected Samba share at /etc/media (on the SSD), it works fine. However, if I setup a password-protected share at /mnt/media (on the RAID array), I keep getting a password prompt regardless of what I enter.
   Anyone have any idea what could be going wrong? Please note that **/dev/sda is my RAID array**, and **/dev/sdb is my SSD**. I've included the contents of some relevant configuration files below.

**/etc/fstab**

```
# DEVICE NAME                                   MOUNT POINT     FS-TYPE OPTIONS                         DUMP-FREQ       PASS-NUM


# RAID5
/dev/sda1                                       /mnt/repo       ext4    defaults                        0               2


# SSD
/dev/sdb1                                       /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077,shortname=winnt      0               0
/dev/sdb2                                       /boot           ext4    defaults                        1               2
/dev/sdb3                                       swap            swap    defaults                        0               0
/dev/sdb4                                       /               ext4    defaults                        1               1


# VIRTUAL FILE SYSTEMS
devpts                                          /dev/pts        devpts  gid=5,mode=620                  0               0
proc                                            /proc           proc    defaults                        0               0
sysfs                                           /sys            sysfs   defaults                        0               0
tmpfs                                           /dev/shm        tmpfs   defaults                        0               0
```

**smb.conf**

```
[global]
bind interfaces only = yes
create mask = 0644
directory mask = 0755
domain master = yes
interfaces = eth0
local master = yes
name resolve order = lmhosts hosts wins bcast
netbios name = SERVER
os level = 65
preferred master = yes
security = SHARE
wins support = yes
workgroup = AWESOME


[media]
hide unreadable = no
path = /var/repo/media
read only = no


[etc-media]
hide unreadable = no
path = /etc/media
read only = no


[media-admin]
browseable = no
path = /mnt/repo/media
read only = no
```

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps caused by the fact that the user you're trying to log in as doesn't have any permissions to access /mnt/repo/media.

Comment: no the permissions are correct. even if I make the user the owner of the whole drive in addition to chmod 755 everywhere, it doesn't make a difference.